# Assignment through chained indexers

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to assign to a DataFrame through chained indexers. Notionally like this:

```
subset = df.loc[mask]
... # much later
subset.loc[mask2, 'column'] += value
```

This does not work because, as I understand it, the second .loc triggers a copy-on-write. Is there a way to do this?

I could pass `df` and `mask` around so that the later code could combine `mask` and `mask2` before making an assignment but it feels much cleaner to be able to pass around the `subset` view instead so that the later code only has to worry about it's own mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to:

```
subset.loc[mask2, 'column']
```

assign this to another subset so you can access its index and columns attributes.

```
subsubset = subset.loc[mask2, 'column']
```

Then you can access `df` with subsubset's index and columns

```
df.loc[subsubset.index, subsubset.columns] += 1
```

Comment: Perhaps my question isn't clear. This is the opposite of what I want. I would like `subset` to be a filtered view of `df` such that assignments made to `subset` will modify the corresponding rows in `df`.

Comment: Understood, one moment... Fixed

Comment: That's still not quite what I was hoping for but using subsubset's index is cleaner than the combining all the masks together as I have been doing. It feels like that's about as close as I'll get to ideal with pandas. Thanks.